# What should I write to test the logged out branch?

Tags: jestjs

Why I write code like this cannot test the logged out branch?
This is the Jest official example.Link is here
https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/jquery
The origin test code is only test logged in branch,so I want to test the whole branch.But I cannot finish it :(

```
  fetchCurrentUser.mockImplementationOnce(cb =>  {
    cb({
      fullName: 'Johnny Cash',
      loggedIn: true,
    });
  }).mockImplementationOnce(cb =>  {
    cb({
      fullName: 'Johnny Cash',
      loggedIn: false,
    });
  });


  $('#button').click();

  expect(fetchCurrentUser).toBeCalled();
  expect($('#username').text()).toEqual('Johnny Cash - Logged In');

  $('#button').click();

  expect(fetchCurrentUser).toBeCalled();
  expect($('#username').text()).toEqual('Johnny Cash - Logged Out');
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause the `fetchCurrentUser` is called initially and only once, before the click happens. So you always get the your first mocked value, which is:

```
cb = > {
  cb({
    fullName: 'Johnny Cash',
    loggedIn: true,
  });
}
```

To test both you can try something like this:

```
let loggedIn = false
fetchCurrentUser.mockImplementationOnce(cb = > {
  loggedIn = !loggedIn
  cb({
    fullName: 'Johnny Cash',
    loggedIn: loggedIn,
  });
})
```

Comment: Also always get the first mocked value :(

Comment: Can you log `loggedIn` before `loggedIn = !loggedIn`.

Comment: before 1st click, loggedIn:  false  after 1st click, loggedIn:  true  before 2nd click, loggedIn:  true  after 2nd click, loggedIn:  true。absolutely the 2nd called is wrong.

Comment: So this seems to work. Now log inside of the callback. Is the correct value passed into it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I find 2nd callback func is not be called.BTW, you konw why?

Comment: Sorry no idea, just maybe you should log what `$('#button')` is the second time

Comment: you are right, the 2nd $("#button") is empty JQ object. ok, I will try to resolve it. thanks!! :)